# Localization crashes my bottom navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, localization

In the project I am working on I am using fance_bottom_navigation package https://pub.dev/packages/fancy_bottom_navigation for my bottom navbar

[image]

This is how it looks like but when I use use localization and just change the language to arabic(rtl language)

[image]

It crashes so is there any way I can work around this? for example can i make the bottom navbar the same whatever language is selected?

This is my code

```
FancyBottomNavigation(
        textColor: Colors.black,
        inactiveIconColor: Color.fromRGBO(169, 169, 169, 1),
        tabs: tabData.reversed
            .map(
                (item) => TabData(iconData: item['icon'], title: item['title']))
            .toList(),
        initialSelection: _pageNumber,
        onTabChangedListener: (position) {
          setState(() {
            _pageNumber = position;
          });
        },
      ),
```